# C Recursive search for a file in a folder and subfolders

Tags: c, windows

My program is getting the input path from the user, and is looking for files with a name corresponding with a column from a .csv file where `oldpath` is the userinput path, and then i'm using `get_between_delimiter` in a while loop to get the name of the file i'm looking for from the first cell of each line in the .csv

What I can't figure out is how do I check all the subdirectories for that file if it does not exist in the base directory or right away, while keeping my program's functionality?

```
  strcpy(oldnp, oldpath);
  strcat(oldnp, "/");
  strcat(oldnp, get_between_delimiter(commande[cnt] , 0));
  strcat(oldnp, ".png");
  source = fopen(oldnp, "r");
  if ((source = fopen(oldnp, "r")) == NULL)
   file_found();
  else
   ;?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) to list all the files in a directory, then compare with each file. Or do a recursive search and search each sub directory.

You can adjust the "wildcard" also.

This example looks for `"something.png"` on `"c:\\test"`, if it doesn't find it, it will look in sub directories of `"c:\\test"`

Make sure you don't do a recursive search on `"C:\"` because that's going to go through all the files on the drive.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int findfile_recursive(const char *folder, const char *filename, char *fullpath)
{
    char wildcard[MAX_PATH];
    sprintf(wildcard, "%s\\*", folder);
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(wildcard, &fd);
    if(handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return 0;
    do  
    {
        if(strcmp(fd.cFileName, ".") == 0 || strcmp(fd.cFileName, "..") == 0) 
            continue;
        char path[MAX_PATH];
        sprintf(path, "%s\\%s", folder, fd.cFileName);

        if(_stricmp(fd.cFileName, filename) == 0) 
            strcpy(fullpath, path);
        else if(fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            findfile_recursive(path, filename, fullpath);
        if(strlen(fullpath))
            break;
    } while(FindNextFile(handle, &fd));
    FindClose(handle);
    return strlen(fullpath);
}

int main(void)
{
    char fullpath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    if(findfile_recursive("c:\\test", "something.png", fullpath))
        printf("found: %s\n", fullpath);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, seems to be working, trying to implement it right now.